# Devolver el foco a un JTextField desde otra clase

Tags: java, jtextfield

Estoy trabajando dentro de la vista con unos JTextField para introducir unos muebles, cuando pulso insertar en la vista, llamo a un método insertarMueble dentro del controlador y este a su vez llama a otro para evaluar si existe el ID.

El caso es que si existe quiero que ademas de salirme un panel, me devuelva el foco al JTextField de ID, el mensaje si lo saco sin problemas, pero el foco no se como devolverlo desde esa casa Controlador. Normalmente siempre lo he devuelto con:

```
txtField.requestFocus();
```

Dejo el código para que os hagais una idea.

Clase Vista:

```
// Boton para insertar un mueble
private void btnInsertarMuebleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    if (txtIdMueble.getText().isEmpty() || txtDescripMueble.getText().isEmpty() || 
        txtPrecioUnitario.getText().isEmpty() || txtUnidadesExistentes.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe rellenar todos los campos.");
        txtIdMueble.requestFocus();
    } else {
        /**
         * Creo un objeto de tipo mueble
         */
        Mueble m = new Mueble();
        m.setIDMueble(Integer.parseInt(txtIdMueble.getText()));
        m.setDescripMueble(txtDescripMueble.getText());
        m.setPrecioUnitario(Float.parseFloat(txtPrecioUnitario.getText()));
        m.setUnidadesExistentes(Integer.parseInt(txtUnidadesExistentes.getText()));

        /**
         * Lladama al metodo de intentoInsertarMueble de la clase
         * operaciones
         */
        Operaciones.intentoInsertarMueble(conexion, m);

    }
}
```

Clase controlador:

```
    /**
     * Intenta insertar un mueble
     * ==========================
     * 
     * @param conexion -> Conexion con la base de datos
     * @param m -> Mueble
     */
    public static void intentoInsertarMueble(ConexionBD conexion, Mueble m){
        if (conexion.insertarMueble(m)) {
            System.out.println("Empleado Insertado");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Empleado NO Insertado");
        }
    }

    public boolean insertarMueble(Mueble m) {
        boolean insertado = true;
        try {
            if (existeMueble(m.getIDMueble())) {
                insertado = false;
            } else {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO MUEBLES_OBJ VALUES(" + m.getIDMueble() 
                        + ", '" + m.getDescripMueble() + "', " + m.getPrecioUnitario() 
                        + ", " + m.getUnidadesExistentes() + ")";
;
                Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
                sentencia.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            insertado = false;
            Logger.getLogger(ConexionBD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return insertado;
    }

public boolean existeMueble(int IDMueble) throws SQLException {
    boolean existe = false;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM MUEBLES_OBJ WHERE IDMUEBLE=" + IDMueble;
    ResultSet resultado = ejecutarConsulta(sql);
    if (resultado.next()) {
        existe = true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ya existe un muble con ese Id, por favor reviselo.");
    }
    return existe;
}
```

Lo que quiero es que método existeMueble ademas de sacarme el panel, me devuelva el foco al campo de ID.

Comment: Probablemente si que te devuelva el foco con eso, pero si dices que sale un panel, al pinchar sobre él ya estas quitandole el foco a ese txtField, prueba a que desde la accion de cerrar el panel haga el foco.

Comment: Es una buena idea, como puedo hacer justo eso, que al darle a aceptar me devuelva el foco, el panel lo muestro asi.

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ya existe un muble con ese Id, por favor reviselo.");

Comment: Implementa a ese MessageDialog un boton con un listener, que cuando pulse sobre ese boton lance el requestFocus

Comment: Alguna idea de como puedo implementar eso, manual o algo?

Comment: Pásate por aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Gracias, pero estoy en las mismas, puedo ejecutar una acción dependiendo del valor devuelto, es decir en teoría de devuelve 0 si el usuario acepta o cierra. Pero como estoy fuera de la clase no se como devolver el foco al JTextField.

Comment: Pues no has compartido nada de código asi que no se te puede ayudar demasiado

Answer (score 1):

A mi se me ocurren estas dos opciones:

- La primera: Puedes hacer que la clase en cuestión tenga un atributo de tipo JTextField, en el constructor de dicha clase haces que ademas de recibir los respectivos argumentos, reciba también un argumento de tipo JTextField, y en el propio constructor inicializas el atributo JTextField igualándolo a el argumento recibido en el constructor, despues en el método simplemente tendrias que llamar a dicho atributo por su nombre y utilizar el metodo requestFocus();

```
// CLASE
   private JTextField nombrequelequierasdar;

// CONSTRUCTOR

   public nombredelaclase (JJTextField tf){
   nombrequelequierasdar = tf;
}

public boolean existeMueble...{

   // codigo con lo que quieras hacer
   nombrequelequierasdar.requestFocus();
}
```

- La segunda opción es que el metodo existeMueble requiera un argumento de tipo JTextField y que cuando llames a dicho método se lo pases como parámetro, si la llamada a dicho método se hace desde la clase controlador no queda otra que utilizar la primera opcion, si embargo si esto se  hace desde otra clase si podría serte útil. Por ejemplo:

```java
public boolean existeMueble(int IDMueble, JTextField tf) throws SQLException {
    boolean existe = false;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM MUEBLES_OBJ WHERE IDMUEBLE=" + IDMueble;
    ResultSet resultado = ejecutarConsulta(sql);
    if (resultado.next()) {
        existe = true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ya existe un muble con ese Id, por favor reviselo.");
    }

    tf.requestFocus();

    return existe;
}
// Ejemplo de llamada a este método:
// Suponiendo que tienes un objeto de la clase controladora instanciado, y que el nombre de tu JTextField es tf

objectoClaseControlador.existeMueble(5,tf);
```

Espero haber podido ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado modificando los JTextField como públicos y estáticos, ahora puedo acceder a ellos:

```
NombreClase.nombreJTextField.resquestFocus();
```